# distributing a specific value into 3 html input tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am writing a code that needs to distribute a value into 3 input tags. So here how it should work,
so a number is fetched from the database named $qtyAvailable. And from there I have 3 input tags cncQty, scatorQty, and manualQty. so the sum of those 3 tags cant exceed $qtyAvailable.  I don't know how to make the jQuery for distributing into those 3 dynamic inputs.

What means by dynamic is for example,  lets say the qtyAvailable is 10, and when user set the cncQty by 10, then the upper limit of the other input tags cant exceed 0. it has to be dynamically allocated into the max="" inside the input tags.

I know I need to use javaScript to dynamically distribute into those 3 inputs but I don't know on how to implement this. Please help me

```
$qtyAvailable = $row['QTY_REQUIRED'] - $row['QTY_CUT'];   

echo '<input class="form-control" id="quantityRequired" name="quantityRequired" type="hidden">';    
echo '<input class="form-control" id="cncQty" name="quantityToCutCnc" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="CNC">';         
echo '<input class="form-control" id="scatorQty" name="quantityToCutScator" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="SCATOR">';       
echo '<input class="form-control" id="manualQty" name="quantityToCutManual" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="MANUAL">';
echo '<br/>';
```

Comment: Just a note: Sometimes it is easy to see what is going on in PHP if you only put the php code in where it needs to be. Try changing `<?php echo '<input class="form-control" id="scatorQty" name="quantityToCutScator" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="SCATOR">'; ?>` to `<input class="form-control" id="scatorQty" name="quantityToCutScator" type="number" min="0" max='<?php echo $qtyAvailable ?>' placeholder="SCATOR">';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
Quantity Required : <span id='quantityRequired'>20</span><br />
<input type='number' name='val1' min='0' value='0' required /> <br />
<input type='number' name='val2' min='0' value='0' required /> <br />
<input type='number' name='val3' min='0' value='0' required />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var 
    total = parseInt($('#quantityRequired').text()),
    inputs = $('input[type="number"]');

inputs
    .attr('max', total)
    .change(function() {

        //Make sure that current value is in range
        if($(this).val() > parseInt($(this).attr('max'))) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('max'));
        } else if ($(this).val() < parseInt($(this).attr('min'))) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('min'));
        }

        //Get currently available total
        var current = available();

        //Now update max on each input
        $('input').each(function(indx) {
            $(this).attr('max',  parseInt($(this).val()) + total - current);
        });
    });

function available() {
    var sum = 0;
    inputs.each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    return sum;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/k2QVV/

Try this. At any time user will not select more than required.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned jquery in the question:

```
 $("input.form-control").change(function() {

  var quantityAvailable =  $("#quantityRequired").val();
  var id = this.id;
  var sum = 0;
  $('input.form-control').each(function() {
    sum+= Number($(this).val());
  });

  $("input.form-control").each(function() {
    if(this.id!=id) {

            $(this).attr("max",quantityAvailable - sum + Number(this.value));

    } 
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <input class="form-control" id="quantityRequired" name="quantityRequired" type="hidden" value="10">

 <input class="form-control" id="cncQty" name="quantityToCutCnc"    type="number" min="0" max='10' placeholder="CNC">         
   <input class="form-control" id="scatorQty" name="quantityToCutScator" type="number" min="0" max='10' placeholder="SCATOR">   
   <input class="form-control" id="manualQty" name="quantityToCutManual" type="number" min="0" max='10' placeholder="MANUAL">
```

Assumption: The hidden field contains the number of availableComponents.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yezih/2/edit)**

Comment: I tried your code but that only works for 2 input tags. when I played it around I can see 4, 4 and 6 in values for the max number of 10

Comment: BTW the answer is quite simple without much computation :P

Answer (score 1):

You may perform validation on the form input prior to submission to check if the total is more than available.

Let say your form has id = "myForm".

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    if (($("#cncQty").val() + $("#scatorQty ").val() + $("#manualQty").val())
           > $("#quantityRequired").val() ) 
    {
        alert( "You have enter more widgets than available!" );
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear. What i gathered is you want to divide the $qtyAvailable into three different values and store each of them in three different tabs. 
If you dont want them equally stored than you can just decrease the $qtyAvailable value by one for each and store them. Like below code :-

```
$qtyAvailable = $row['QTY_REQUIRED'] - $row['QTY_CUT'];   
echo '<input class="form-control" id="quantityRequired" name="quantityRequired" type="hidden">';

$cncQty  = $qtyAvailable -1;
 echo '<input class="form-control" id="cncQty" name="quantityToCutCnc"    type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="CNC" value="'.$cncQty.'">';         

$scatorQty = $cncQty - 1;
 echo '<input class="form-control" id="scatorQty" name="quantityToCutScator" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="SCATOR" value="'.$scatorQty .'">';       

 $manualQty= $scatorQty - 1;
 echo '<input class="form-control" id="manualQty" name="quantityToCutManual" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="MANUAL" value="'.$scatorQty .'" >';
   echo '<br/>';
```